# Animating ImageView in Android

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I am a newbie to Android development and am exploring the animation section of Android.

The requirement in my application is something like this -

1. Screen1 loads with a background image
2. Screen2 loads with image1 from left and image2 from the right with the background 
   image remaining unchanged
3. Screen3 loads with image3 at the top center of image1 and image2 with the background image remaining intact

I have been able to achieve this partially through alpha animation and using `overridePendingTransition()`  functionalities. In my case, though I use the same background image in all the screens, but the animation is getting applied on the whole layout. I intend to apply the animation on the individual images. Any pointers as to how to achieve this would be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the link provided by the @nik431 you can also refer to API demos. It contains all the stock android features provided by the sdk and how to use it.
http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/6356d3a9ceb5b505/2b427545090cb32f

Answer (score 0):

To perform these animation you need to go through Translate Animation. These are the steps to create translate animation

- Create a TranslateAnimation object.
- Set the required attributes like setFillAfter, setAnimationListener, setDuration, setInterpolater, etc
- Call yourview.startAnimation(translate animation obj) to start the animation.**

syntax:

TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 500,0, 0);

animation.setDuration(1000);

yourviewobject.startAnimation(animation);